# Why can't I see my app in the avd app menu?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-virtual-device

My app successfully installs on my AVD, I can confirm it was installed by seeing it in the app manager, but I can never access it because I can not see it in the app menu

In the console I always get the messages

> [2011-12-27 10:39:28 - WhosurSensei] No Launcher activity found!
>
> [2011-12-27 10:39:28 - WhosurSensei] The launch will only sync the
>   application package on the device!

my opening java page

```
package com.thepackage.WhosurSensei;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WhosurSenseiActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstpagebutton);  
   Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

        public void onClick(View v) {   
            startActivity(new Intent(WhosurSenseiActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
        }  
    });    
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

my androidmanifest page

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".WhosurSenseiActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.thepackage.WhosurSensei.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainMenu" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the tutorial I was reading told me wrong and I needed this in the manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```